# iPhone UITextField inputView error: Assignement to readonly property

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am having issues when I want to assign UIPicker as inputView of UITextField. It shows error " ***Assignement to readonly property***". Please help as I think it is not related to property sythesizing.

I have added my code below:

```
@interface DriverWaitingDetails : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{

IBOutlet UILabel *baseLabel;
IBOutlet UITableView *driverTableView;
IBOutlet UIPickerView *basePicker;
}

 @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *basePicker;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *baseLabel;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView *driverTableView;


@end
```

Implementation Code:-

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

basePicker=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,320, 500)];
self.navigationItem.title=@"Driver Table";
baseLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
basePicker.delegate = self;
basePicker.dataSource = self;
[basePicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
baseLabel.inputView=nil;
[super viewDidLoad];    
}
```

Attached Screenshot:-
[image: UITextField Error Image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the input view of `UILabel`.
You declared baseLabel as `UILabel` not `UITextField`.

```
IBOutlet UILabel *baseLabel;
```

Comment: Ok...I just realized my mistake. I feel like a dumb. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared

`IBOutlet UILabel *baseLabel;`

UILabel inherits from `UIView : UIResponder : NSObject` and the property is defined in `UIResponder`:

```
@property (readonly, retain) UIView *inputView
```

As the property `inputView` is read only, you cannot assign any value to it.